# Error in imputer.fit when preprocessing data

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.6.7
IPython 7.4.0
Navigator/Spyder

Hi, I'm getting `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 3, None))' is an invalid key` when using this code

```
#Importing Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Importing the Dataset

dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")

#Independant & Dependant Variables

X = dataset.iloc[: , :-1]
Y = dataset.iloc[: , 3]

#Missing Data

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = "mean", 
                        fill_value=None, verbose=0, copy=True)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[: , 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```

The error i get is:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy = "mean", 
                        fill_value=None, verbose=0, copy=True)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[: , 1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-a1bcee2e6448>", line 4, in <module>
    imputer = imputer.fit(X[: , 1:3])

  File "C:\Users\Farouk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", 
line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\Farouk\Anaconda3\lib\site-
```

packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(key)

```
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in 
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 110, in 
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), slice(1, 3, None))' is an invalid 
key
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Worked after using   "imputer = imputer.fit(X.iloc[:, 1:3])
X.iloc[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X.iloc[:, 1:3])"

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleImputer`'s `fit_transform` fonction is expecting an narray not a `pandas.DataFrame`

```
X = dataset.iloc[: , :-1].values
Y = dataset.iloc[: , 3].values
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html